# In Need For Speed: World, is there any gameplay difference between the Lustra, React and Glint packages?

Tags: pc, need-for-speed-world

NFS:W, after you painstakingly reach level 5, offers you a whooping choice of three performance upgrade packs: Lustra, React and Glint.

As much as I'd rather get a new ride -- something that was far easier in NFS:MW -- I'll have to consider getting a package instead (mainly for pursuit purposes).

Which one exactly? Is there any gameplay difference at all? They all cost the same and all upgrade car stats by the same -- this fake choice kind of puzzles me.

Comment: Obviously I can't get a new car because I didn't pay the $20 to unlock levels 11-50...

Comment: This really annoys me too; as far as I can tell the differences are just cosmetic, but I have no way to be sure.  Fortunately, they're bringing "slot-based performance customization" in a future update: http://www.needforspeed.com/post/new-roads-rides-and-modes-coming-need-speed-world?cat=44

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZoogieZork's comment and the offical blog post seem to imply that no, there is no gameplay difference indeed. Not yet, anyway.